# how to write double array in a user-defined structure by c and pass to python with ctype

Tags: python, c++, struct, ctypes

My goal is C writing to the structure members, and pass the structure pointer back to python.
The structure consists 2 same size double arrays(which stand for real part and imag part data,) # of row in the array, # of col.
Since it is row major in Python, I could pass 2d array by type POINTER(double), and given row&col I could access the right position. (instead of POINTER(POINTER(c_double)))

in Python

```
class tx_data(Structure):
  _fields_=[("I", POINTER(c_double)), ("m", c_int), ("n", c_int), ("Q", POINTER(c_double))]
# argtypes& restype for preventing invalid data
writereturn = lib.WriteReturn
writei= lib.WriteI
writereturn.argtypes = [c_int,c_int]
writereturn.restype=POINTER(tx_data)
writei.argtypes = [c_int,c_int,POINTER(tx_data)]
writei.restype= None
```

The function WriteI pass the instance of structure with zero-filled data, I would like arrays to be filled data by C. However, the data didn't change. I am not sure if it is not possible to pass pointer of structure and the structure also contains pointer to double

```
def WriteI(Nrow, len):
  txData_pointer = POINTER(tx_data)
  rec_data = tx_data()
  I = np.zeros((Nrow,len), dtype=np.double)
  Q = np.zeros((Nrow,len), dtype=np.double)
  rec_data.I = I.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
  rec_data.Q = Q.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
  rec_data.m = c_int(Nrow)
  rec_data.n = c_int(len)
  print(addressof(rec_data))
  print(txData_pointer.from_address(addressof(rec_data)))
  print("in PY--m:%d, n:%d"%(Nrow,len))
  writei(Nrow, len, txData_pointer.from_address(addressof(rec_data)))
  #rx(Nrow, len, byref(rec_data))
  return rec_data
```

Then I saw other post, returning the write data by POINTER(structure). I try as following, yet pops out **OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000000**

```
def WriteReturn(Nrow, len):
    rec_data = tx_data.from_address(writereturn(Nrow, len))
    xk = tx_data()
    xk.I = cast(rec_data.contents.I, POINTER(c_double))
    xk.Q = cast(rec_data.contents.Q, POINTER(c_double))
    xk.m = c_int(Nrow)
    xk.n = c_int(len)
    return xk
```

in Header.h

```
typedef struct{
  double *I;
  int m;
  int n;
  double *Q;
}tx_data;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void WriteI(int Nrow, int len, tx_data &xk); 
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) tx_data* WriteReturn(int Nrow, int len);
```

in C++

```
void WriteI(int Nrow, int len, tx_data &xk) {
  size_t t;
  for (int i = 0; i < Nrow; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
          t = len * i + j;
          xk.I[t] = 0.3+t;
          xk.Q[t] = 0.7+t;
      }
  }
}
tx_data* WriteReturn(int Nrow, int len) {
  tx_data* xk = new tx_data();
  size_t t;
  xk->m = Nrow;
  xk->n = len;
  for (int i = 0; i < Nrow; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
          t = len * i + j;
          xk->I[t] = 0.3 + t;
          xk->Q[t] = 0.7 + t;
      }
  }
  return xk;
}
```

Could anyone shed some light of how to fix it?

Comment: For your `WriteI` function in C++, if you replace `tx_data &xk` with `tx_data *xk`, and replace both instances of `xk.` with `xk->`, does anything change?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, in C++, i pass by reference `tx_data &xk `, the data could not be overwrite. but change to `tx_data *xk` ,it show the same error message as  ** ''access violation writing 0x0000000000000000'' ** . Should I change the type in python i pass through ctypes for &xk and *xk?, In python I pass byref(rec_data) and rec_data doesn't matter for &xk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of problems here.

First, `txData_pointer.from_address(addressof(rec_data))` is wrong. That's basically the C equivalent of `*(tx_data **)&rec_data`, which is obviously wrong since `rec_data` isn't a pointer. If you want to be complicated for no reason, then do `tx_data.from_address(addressof(rec_data))` instead, but if you want to be simple, then just do `byref(rec_data)`.

After that, `tx_data.from_address(writereturn(Nrow, len))` is wrong. There's no need to involve `from_address` here; just save the result of `writereturn`.

Next, `void WriteI(int Nrow, int len, tx_data &xk)` is wrong. You can't use `&`s in function signatures that you're declaring `extern "C"`. Use a `*` instead of an `&`, and change `WriteI` to use `xk->` instead of `xk.`.

Finally, in `WriteReturn`, you're creating a new `tx_data`, but not allocating an `I` or `Q` for it, despite attempting to write into them. You need to do `xk->I = new double[Nrow * len];`, and the same for `Q`.

With all of that fixed, your code works. Here it is with the fixes (your `class` in Python is fine as-is, so I didn't repost it):

```py
def WriteI(Nrow, len):
  rec_data = tx_data()
  I = np.zeros((Nrow,len), dtype=np.double)
  Q = np.zeros((Nrow,len), dtype=np.double)
  rec_data.I = I.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
  rec_data.Q = Q.ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_double))
  rec_data.m = c_int(Nrow)
  rec_data.n = c_int(len)
  print(addressof(rec_data))
  print("in PY--m:%d, n:%d"%(Nrow,len))
  writei(Nrow, len, byref(rec_data))
  #rx(Nrow, len, byref(rec_data))
  return rec_data
```

```py
def WriteReturn(Nrow, len):
    rec_data = writereturn(Nrow, len)
    xk = tx_data()
    xk.I = cast(rec_data.contents.I, POINTER(c_double))
    xk.Q = cast(rec_data.contents.Q, POINTER(c_double))
    xk.m = c_int(Nrow)
    xk.n = c_int(len)
    return xk
```

```cpp
typedef struct{
  double *I;
  int m;
  int n;
  double *Q;
}tx_data;

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void WriteI(int Nrow, int len, tx_data *xk);
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) tx_data* WriteReturn(int Nrow, int len);
```

```cpp
void WriteI(int Nrow, int len, tx_data *xk) {
  size_t t;
  for (int i = 0; i < Nrow; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
          t = len * i + j;
          xk->I[t] = 0.3+t;
          xk->Q[t] = 0.7+t;
      }
  }
}
tx_data* WriteReturn(int Nrow, int len) {
  tx_data* xk = new tx_data();
  size_t t;
  xk->I = new double[Nrow * len];
  xk->m = Nrow;
  xk->n = len;
  xk->Q = new double[Nrow * len];
  for (int i = 0; i < Nrow; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
          t = len * i + j;
          xk->I[t] = 0.3 + t;
          xk->Q[t] = 0.7 + t;
      }
  }
  return xk;
}
```

And by the way, there's a ton of stuff you can do to improve this code that I didn't go over. This is just the bare minimum changes necessary to get it to work.

Comment: I would change the python code coordinating with `void WriteI(int Nrow, int len, tx_data *xk)`, to declare the size inside the structure

`def WriteI(Nrow, len):
    writei.argtypes = [c_int, c_int, POINTER(tx_data)]
    rec_data = tx_data()
    rec_data.I = (c_double *10000)() #10000 is optional, just to be big enough to receive
    rec_data.Q = (c_double *10000)()
    rec.data.m = c_int(Nrow)
    rec_data.n = c_int(len)
    rx(Nrow, len, byref(rec_data))
    return rec_data
`

Comment: @WeiInu Why? The way it is now makes it the right size, and yours potentially wastes a ton of space and is potentially too small.

Comment: I consider that originally declare zero ndarray then cast to pointer for I and Q could be changed to a pointer point to an double array of size Nrow* len. would the latter one also waste more space?

Comment: @WeiInu I'm not sure what you mean. Can you explain it in code too? Also, what's wrong with just allocating them the way we are now?